# Optimization on D-Wave quantum annealer (application in finance)

Tags: portfolio-optimization, quantum-finance

**Does anybody know wheter any bank uses D-Wave quantum annealer for doing optimization?**

Quantum annealers are single purpose quatum computers used for optimization. They implement quantum simulated annealing physically and thus they use real quantum effects, not simulated as on classical computers. For this they should be faster than classical computers and in theory more reliable (or in other words, a probability that optimal solution is found instead of sub-optimal one is higher).

D-Wave is a provider of such machines. As I know its customers comprise e.g. Volkswagen or Lockheed Martin (according to D-Wave website). However, I would like to know if any bank is a customer of D-Wave.

Comment: "know if any bank is a customer of D-Wave", would applications in market making, investing (passive or active) or insurance also be of interest?

Comment: @BobJansen: Any application in banking, finance etc. Simply I am courious whether any bank has engaged in D-Wave quantum computer.